# How to add line breaks in a mapped array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have to folowing KO Object:

```
var Property= function (data) {
    this.name= ko.observable(data[0].name);
    this.address = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        return data.map(function (prop) {
            return prop.address;
        });
    }, this);
}
```

The JSON 'data' is as follow:

> [{"name":"Name1","address":"Address1"}{"name":"Name1","address":"Address2"}]

When I show on the page the 'address' property,

```
<span data-bind="text: address"></span>
```

It looks like this:

> Address1 ,Address2

My question is how can I seperate between the addresses with a line break instead of a comma?

> Address1
>
> Address2

I tried that:

```
    var Property= function (data) {
    this.name= ko.observable(data[0].name);
    this.address = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        return data.map(function (prop) {
            return prop.address + '\n';
        });
    }, this);
}
```

But the output was:

> Address1 \n,Address2 \n

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: you could add a linebreak `<br>` instead of a linefeed.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that, it simply hardcoded it.. 'Address1 <br>, Address2 <br>'..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\n` is not how HTML like breaks works. You need to use proper layout for that, at the minimum, use `<br />`.

You can concatenate your entries like this:

```
return data.map(function (prop) {
      return prop.address;
}).join('<br/>');
```

Also, you need to bind the value as HTML for markup to be retained, use:

```
<span data-bind="html: address"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! Changing the bind type to HTML did it! Thanks a Million!!!